# How to select even items of all elements

Tags: css-selectors

The HTML structure is as follows. Could you please tell me how to use CSS to select even items of all P elements? Thanks!

```
<section>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just can use this selector:

```
.item > p:nth-child(even) {
  /* some styles here */
}

.item > p:nth-child(odd) {
  /* some styles here */
}
```

this will select all direct child of `.item` class and apply your `odd` or `even` styles to them, if you want to dismis the direct relationship selection, just use `.item p:nth-child(even) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Set background all `P` element

```
p {
background-color:red;
}
```

Set background all `item` class

```
.item{
background-color:red;
}
```

Set background with id that `unique`. *ID is unique. This can set just one element.*

```
#unique {
background-color:red;
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Even term, not just one element.

Comment: You can use ``p{//some code section}``. When you write just ``p`` CSS effects all p items.