# How to select even elements by class name with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been trying to change color of these divs through a click of a button. But I've been unable to select the EVEN divs like in CSS -> nth-child(even).

Help me select oonly even divs with class name 'newBox'. **Thank You**

```
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main_box');

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const newBox = document.createElement('div');
  newBox.classList.add('newBox');
  mainContainer.appendChild(newBox);
}

function change() {
  //I want here to select only the even divs
  document.querySelectorAll('.newBox').forEach((divs) => {
    divs.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  })
}
```

Comment: Did you tried `document.querySelectorAll('.newBox:nth-child(even)')` ??

Comment: @Sakil, answers go down there. You short-circuit the SO process when you post them as comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select even items of all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013270/how-to-select-even-items-of-all-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `:nth-child` selector like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('.newBox:nth-child(even)')
```

read more about it in [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

By the way this is duplicate

Answer (score 1):

> Use **document.querySelectorAll('.newBox:nth-child(even)')**

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main_box');

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const newBox = document.createElement('div');
    newBox.classList.add('newBox');
    mainContainer.appendChild(newBox);
}

function change() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.newBox:nth-child(even)').forEach((divs) => {
       divs.style.backgroundColor = "green";
   })
}
change();
```

```css
.newBox {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box"></div>
```